# Issues with connecting a Neo4j 2.2.3 graph.db with a gremlin 2.6.0 console or rexster 2.6.0 interface

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, gremlin, rexster

*What i have done ..*

- Trying to connect to graph.db generated by neo4j 2.2.3 so as to work with the sample Movie graph (to use other graphs later on..) after saving the  Movie nodes and relationships by running the cypher query for Movie Graph in neo4j interface at localhost:7474
- Manually installed the Blueprints implementation for Neo4j 2.x as instructed here https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/Specific-Graph-Configurations .. also updated the Rexster.xml

After updating the  in Rexter.xml to my graph.db, tried to access the graph from *localhost:8182/graphs/neo4jsample/tp/gremlin?script=g.V.map()* 
but it returns `{"message":"Graph [neo4jsample] could not be found"}`

From gremlin console `g = new Neo4jGraph('*path/to/my/graph.db*')`

throws

```
org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@9d35b10' was successfully initialized, but failed to start.
```

Is it that Neo4j 2.x implementation is not yet supported by Rexster and Gremlin or did I not go through all the required steps to configure it right?

Grateful for any pointers!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rexster/Gremlin 2.x support a slightly older version of Neo4j:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blob/master/blueprints-neo4j2-graph/pom.xml#L15

though I doubt that to be your problem exactly.  If you can't connect to your graph with the Gremlin Console then it won't work in Rexster so you took the right approach in trying that.  Of course, Gremlin Console doesn't ship with the Neo4j 2.x if I recall correct - it has to be "installed" (copy in the dependencies to the path of the console).

Unless you have a reason for doing so, I'd consider leaving TinkerPop 2.x behind and look at the newly released 3.x.  It supports Neo4j 2.x directly and represents the new direction of TinkerPop:

http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-incubating/#neo4j-gremlin

Comment: Thank you @Stephen! Will try connecting using TinkerPop 3.x.